# How to create Expression filter for <T> List Comparison?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list comparison function which is given below

```
public delegate bool CompareValue<in T1, in T2>(T1 val1, T2 val2);
    public static bool CompareTwoLists<T1, T2>(IEnumerable<T1> list1, IEnumerable<T2> list2, CompareValue<T1, T2> compareValue)
    {
        return list1.Select(item1 => list2.Any(item2 => compareValue(item1, item2))).All(search => search)
                && list2.Select(item2 => list1.Any(item1 => compareValue(item1, item2))).All(search => search);
    }
```

And this function is calling like below

```
bool IsSuccess1 = ListComparison.CompareTwoLists(listProduct, listProduct2, (listProductx, listProductx2) => listProductx.ProductName == listProductx2.ProductName);
```

Here delegate expression is static now. This is using to compare a particular column in two list items. How to create above code dynamically based on a list

```
List<CompareColumns> listCompareColumns = new List<Classes.CompareColumns>(); 

CompareColumns objDup1 = new CompareColumns(); 
objDup1.Columns = "ProductName"; 

CompareColumns objDup2 = new CompareColumns(); 
objDup2.Columns = "ProductCode"; 

listCompareColumns.Add(objDup1); 
listCompareColumns.Add(objDup2);
```

Above list may have one or more columns. We need to compare these columns in the comparison lists. based on the above list how to generate below code dynamically?

```
(listProductx, listProductx2) => listProductx.ProductName == listProductx2.ProductName && listProductx.ProductCode == listProductx2.ProductCode && etc....
```

Comment: What does the `CompareColumn` list contain? The name of the properties? Or selector expressions like `x => x.ProductName`?

Comment: @Yacoub Massad CompareColumn list contains; what and all fields we need to compare. eg: ProductName, ProductCode, etc... In other two list have Product Details which have many columns. But only compare with 'CompareColumns'.

Comment: @Pradu please show us `CompareColumns`' definition?

Comment: `List<DuplicateExpression> listDuplicateExpression = new List<Classes.DuplicateExpression>();

            DuplicateExpression objDup1 = new DuplicateExpression();
            objDup1.ExpressionName = "ProductName";            
            DuplicateExpression objDup2 = new DuplicateExpression();
            objDup2.ExpressionName = "ProductCode";

            listDuplicateExpression.Add(objDup1);
            listDuplicateExpression.Add(objDup2);'

Comment: `List<CompareColumns> listCompareColumns = new List<Classes.CompareColumns>();

            CompareColumns objDup1 = new CompareColumns();
            objDup1.Columns = "ProductName";
            CompareColumns objDup2 = new CompareColumns();
            objDup2.Columns = "ProductCode";

            listCompareColumns.Add(objDup1);
            listCompareColumns.Add(objDup2);`

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use the comparison function (`CompareValue<T1, T2> compareValue`) a lot of times, then it would make sense to create an expression and compile it. Here is an example:

```
public static CompareValue<T1, T2> CreateComparer<T1, T2>(List<CompareColumns> columns)
{
    var propertyNames = columns.Select(x => x.Columns).ToList();

    var param1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T1), "val1");
    var param2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T2), "val2");

    var expressionBody =
        propertyNames
            .Select(propertyName =>
                Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.Property(param1, propertyName),
                    Expression.Property(param2, propertyName)))
            .Aggregate(Expression.AndAlso);

    return
        Expression
            .Lambda<CompareValue<T1, T2>>(
                expressionBody,
                param1,
                param2)
            .Compile();
}
```

Here is how to use it:

```
List<CompareColumns> columns = ...

var func = CreateComparer<Class1,Class2>(columns);

var result = CompareTwoLists<Class1,Class2>(listOfClass1, listOfClass2 , func);
```

Comment: Where to call this function?

Comment: var func = ListComparison.CreateComparer<listProduct, listProduct2>(listCompareColumns); I am getting error listProduct,listProduct2 could not be bound

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `listCompareColumns` can be defined in `compareValue` function you can do this using [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656691.aspx):

```
bool CmpVal<T1, T2>(T1 val1, T2 val2)
{
     var listCompareColumns = new List<CompareColumns>();
     //fill list values

     return listCompareColumns
              .All(q => typeof(T1).GetProperty(q.Columns, BindingFlags.Public | 
                                                          BindingFlags.Instance)
                                  .GetValue(val1) ==
                        typeof(T2).GetProperty(q.Columns, BindingFlags.Public | 
                                                          BindingFlags.Instance)
                                  .GetValue(val2));
}
```

Comment: Iam getting NullReference Error

Comment: @Pradu, where is it you are getting the error at? I guess it would be because properties are not found. Are they public properties (with `get` and `set` accessors)? Are you sure all objects have desired properties?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in. I am getting this error. properly getting values in q.columns and val1 and va2.

Comment: @Pradu, I understand that you are getting the exception, I also suggested that there are no public properties with names you have set in `listCompareColumns` in either `T1` or `T2`. Did you check that?

Comment: all are public variables

Comment: variables meaning fields instead of properties? in this case replace `GetProperty` with `GetField`

Comment: public class Product
    {
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductType { get; set; }
        public string Amount { get; set; }
    }

Comment: public class DuplicateExpression
    {
        public string ExpressionName { get; set; }
    }