# How to create a <T> function for list comparison?

Tags: c#, linq

```
public static bool CompareLists(List<Product> lstProduct1, List<Product> lstProduct2, List<DuplicateExpression> DuplicateExpression)
    {
        string[] Fields = DuplicateExpression.Select(x => x.ExpressionName).ToArray();
        //var JoinExp = lstProduct1.Join(lstProduct2, new[] { "ProductName", "ProductCode" });
        var JoinExp = lstProduct1.Join(lstProduct2, Fields);
        bool IsSuccess = CompareTwoLists(lstProduct1, lstProduct2, (listProductx1, listProductx2) => JoinExp.Any());

        return IsSuccess;
    }
```

How to convert above function as `<T>` function?. Actually this is a List comparison function.

Comment: If you want generic function for list comparison, you can find answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669970/compare-two-listt-objects-for-equality-ignoring-order

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Expression filter for <T> List Comparison?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39387200/how-to-create-expression-filter-for-t-list-comparison)

Answer (score 1):

SequenceEqual solves your problem.

```
new[] { "A", "B" }.SequenceEqual(new[] { "A", "B" }).Should().BeTrue();
```

Here is the source code.

```
public static bool SequenceEqual<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    if (comparer == null) comparer = EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default;
    if (first == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("first");
    if (second == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("second");
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e1 = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e2 = second.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (e1.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!(e2.MoveNext() && comparer.Equals(e1.Current, e2.Current)))
                return false;
        }
        if (e2.MoveNext())
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In your case you could elect to replace `IEnumerable<TSource>` with `IList<TSource>` or even `List<TSource>` ideally the highest level of [abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_abstraction) is preferred.